# Make a container appear when field is valid with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm new to jQuery.

I'm using a jQuery plugin called jQuery Validate. I tried looking at examples on their website but I couldn't find anything similar to mine.

I've tried various methods but I couldn't get it to work.

The idea is to show Data Container when the user has successfully filled in their zipcode and click on the button. It shouldn't appear when they press the enter keyboard button.

```js
$("#searchForm").validate({
    rules: {
        text: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 7
        }
    }
});

$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
    $(".even").removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image: radial-gradient(51.26% 104.44%, #313B4B 0%, #222831 100%);
    padding: 35px 30px;
}

li {
    color: #92B572;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h4,
span {
    color: #B9E4FA;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 130px;
    color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: light;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

label,
p {
    color: #B9E4FA;
    font-family: "FSElliot";
    font-size: 20px;
}

input {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 67px;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: none;
}

button {
    background-color: #70BBB7;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    outline-style: none;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #497E7B;
}

.center-block {
    line-height: 140px;
}

input:active,
input:focus,
button:active,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.rectangle {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #313B4B 0%, #2C3640 100%);
    opacity: 0.15;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.uprnResult {
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3.8px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.data-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

.data-oval {
    background-color: #FBF6EF;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.data-rectangle {
    background-color: #3A4554;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    opacity: 0.7442336309523809;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}


div.data-rectangle h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div.data-rectangle h3:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -35px;
    left: 50%;
}

div.data-rectangle h3+p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rawData-headers {
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.rawData-headers h4 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.rawData-container {
    background-color: #3A4554;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    opacity: 0.7442336309523809;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 15px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d7ccf5cd0f.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
        </article>
        <!-- Logo section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <div class="logo"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!-- Headers section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1>Test</h1>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!-- Form section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <form id="searchForm">
                            <label>Zip Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="text">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 center-block">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="trigger">Submit!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
            <!-- Data Container -->
            <div class="even hide">
                <article>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="data-container">
                                    <div class="data-oval">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="data-rectangle">
                                        <h3>Data</h3>
                                        <p>4</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </article>
            </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the field is [`valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)(each field in a form using this plugins has that method) whenever user types or changes it's value:

```
$("#searchForm input").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).valid()) {
    $("#data-container").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#data-container").hide();
  }
});
```

Your updated snippet:

```js
$("#searchForm").validate({
    rules: {
        text: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 7
        }
    }
});

$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
    $(".even").removeClass("hide");
});

$("#searchForm input").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).valid()) {
    $("#data-container").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#data-container").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image: radial-gradient(51.26% 104.44%, #313B4B 0%, #222831 100%);
    padding: 35px 30px;
}

li {
    color: #92B572;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h4,
span {
    color: #B9E4FA;
}

h3 {
    padding-top: 130px;
    color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: light;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

label,
p {
    color: #B9E4FA;
    font-family: "FSElliot";
    font-size: 20px;
}

input {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 67px;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: none;
}

button {
    background-color: #70BBB7;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    outline-style: none;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #497E7B;
}

.center-block {
    line-height: 140px;
}

input:active,
input:focus,
button:active,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.rectangle {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #313B4B 0%, #2C3640 100%);
    opacity: 0.15;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.uprnResult {
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3.8px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.data-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

.data-oval {
    background-color: #FBF6EF;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.data-rectangle {
    background-color: #3A4554;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    opacity: 0.7442336309523809;
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}


div.data-rectangle h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div.data-rectangle h3:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: -35px;
    left: 50%;
}

div.data-rectangle h3+p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rawData-headers {
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.rawData-headers h4 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.rawData-container {
    background-color: #3A4554;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    opacity: 0.7442336309523809;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 15px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d7ccf5cd0f.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
        </article>
        <!-- Logo section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <div class="logo"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!-- Headers section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1>Test</h1>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <!-- Form section -->
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <form id="searchForm">
                            <label>Zip Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="text">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 center-block">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="trigger">Submit!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
            <!-- Data Container -->
            <div class="even hide" id="data-container">
                <article>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="data-container">
                                    <div class="data-oval">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="data-rectangle">
                                        <h3>Data</h3>
                                        <p>4</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </article>
            </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```